# zfloat directive for angular no work

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm using breeze 1.5.0 and angular 1.3.0 rc1 I'm binding directly to a breeze entity to a property of type `decimal?` using the input in html table like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in vm.items">
        <td ng-repeat="c in i.children">
            <div>
                <input ng-model="c.value" z-float />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But comma and decimal point are ignored after entered a number [0-9]. For example I did'n enter the value "9.99".

I try this, but It didn't work. I did'n enter decimal values:

```
<input ng-model="vm.items[0].children[0].value" z-float />
```

I used "Angular Float Directive" more information [here](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesfloat).

Comment: What is z-float directive? Never seen it and can't find documentation for it. 

Comment: "Angular Float Directive" documentation [here](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesfloat)

Comment: Hah. Forgot about that ... and I wrote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with Breeze. They broke it in Angular.1.3.0.  Now I have to find how and why.

FWIW, commas NEVER worked. JavaScript doesn't support ',' when parsing numeric strings and neither does it support internationalization of numbers (e.g., ',' for a decimal point).

### Update 22 Sept 2014

Discovered they broke the signature of $formatters for v.1.3.0 and didn't tell anyone.See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9218

I have updated *breeze.angular.directives* to v.1.3.9 so it should now work with both versions.

See updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/E2HgF7ASNWIdwsvzs5G0?p=preview which changed the zFloat model-value/element-value comparison from

```
return (value === +viewValue) ? viewValue : value;
```

to

```
return (+viewValue === +modelValue) ? viewValue : modelValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but some how below code is working for me. I changed zFloat directive in my local file.

```
return (+viewValue === +modelValue) ? viewValue : modelValue;
```

to

```
return (+viewValue === +modelValue) ? modelValue: viewValue;
```